# Microsoft Graph Api upload file to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using microsoft graph api to interview with sharepoint.

1. Upload file to sharepoint.

   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc78c05-a77b-45bf-a1a1-51f09548b497/drive/root:/test1212123.txt:/content
2. Then we can got the response.

   ```
    {
   "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('abc78c05-a77b-45bf-a1a1-51f09548b497')/drive/root/$entity",
   "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://yeeofficesg.sharepoint.com/sites/GdTest/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=b9d25e13-c915-432f-b9fb-f2d36a188d9f&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.aTVxeDdWNkowcWFDK0xYOHUvZGo3K0VVSEd1dU02MFVheEFJbnBWWUJHTT0&ApiVersion=2.0",
   "createdDateTime": "2020-03-20T05:34:59Z",
   "eTag": "\"{B9D25E13-C915-432F-B9FB-F2D36A188D9F},1\"",
   "id": "016REKDTITL3JLSFOJF5B3T67S2NVBRDM7",
   "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-20T05:34:59Z",
   "name": "test1212123.txt",
   "webUrl": "https://yeeofficesg.sharepoint.com/sites/GdTest/Shared%20Documents/test1212123.txt",
   "cTag": "\"c:{B9D25E13-C915-432F-B9FB-F2D36A188D9F},1\"",
   "size": 12,
   "createdBy": {
       "application": {
           "id": "597d48bc-05f3-4158-8acc-ae5cc7a9c6ad",
           "displayName": "HttpRequest Test"
       }
   },
   "lastModifiedBy": {
       "application": {
           "id": "597d48bc-05f3-4158-8acc-ae5cc7a9c6ad",
           "displayName": "HttpRequest Test"
       }
   },
   "parentReference": {
       "driveId": "b!BYzHq3unv0WhoVHwlUi0l_EO2rYM2NNCptmOTvJ-EqeM9aeJ-zj_TZktSrctfA1S",
       "driveType": "documentLibrary",
       "id": "016REKDTN6Y2GOVW7725BZO354PWSELRRZ",
       "path": "/drive/root:"
   },
   "file": {
       "mimeType": "text/plain",
       "hashes": {
           "quickXorHash": "RBBCDGQwAxrUIARAFAEJSgAAAAA="
       }
   },
   "fileSystemInfo": {
       "createdDateTime": "2020-03-20T05:34:59Z",
       "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-03-20T05:34:59Z"
   }
   }
   ```
3. Then I want to update the customized column of this list.
   https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc78c05-a77b-45bf-a1a1-51f09548b497/lists/89a7f58c-38fb-4dff-992d-4ab72d7c0d52/items/80/fields
4. step3, I needs the item id (this example is : 80)
   but when I upload the file, I can't got the item id directly from the response.

use this api:https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc78c05-a77b-45bf-a1a1-51f09548b497/lists/89a7f58c-38fb-4dff-992d-4ab72d7c0d52/items/
I can got the items list which include the item id is needed.

Finally, my question is ,when I upload file to sharepoint, how can I got the item id which is needed by update item.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up extracting the Item GUID from the response, i.e.

"@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "https://yeeofficesg.sharepoint.com/sites/GdTest/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=**b9d25e13-c915-432f-b9fb-f2d36a188d9f**&Translate=false&tempauth=....

or

"eTag": ""{**B9D25E13-C915-432F-B9FB-F2D36A188D9F**},1""

or

"cTag": ""c:{**B9D25E13-C915-432F-B9FB-F2D36A188D9F**},1""

And then use that in the PATCH call where the item ID is required, i.e. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/abc78c05-a77b-45bf-a1a1-51f09548b497/lists/89a7f58c-38fb-4dff-992d-4ab72d7c0d52/items/**B9D25E13-C915-432F-B9FB-F2D36A188D9F**/fields

Might be a more elegant way to solve the problem, however this worked for me